# Expresión regular para escapar saltos de línea

Tags: php, python, regex

Tengo un *string* en PHP que contiene código en Python, como a continuación:

```
$codigo_fuente = "\nprint('Hola\nMundo')\n";
```

Resulta que necesito escapar los saltos de línea que se encuentran entre comillas simples o dobles, ya que el contenido del *string* se lo entrego a una API para que ejecute el código a través del interprete de Python, pero el interprete de Python al tomar los saltos de línea que están entre comillas simples o dobles los considera como los saltos de línea que sirven para organizar el código, es por eso que el contenido del *string* para el interprete de Python es el siguiente:

```
print('Hola
Mundo')
```

Por lo tanto, necesito tener el siguiente resultado después de aplicar una expresión regular:

```
$nuevo_codigo = "\nprint('Hola\\nMundo')\n";
```

En otras palabras, simplemente anteceder con un `\` cualquier ocurrencia de `\n` que esté contenida dentro de comillas simples o dobles.

Llevo esto en PHP de momento para el caso que se encuentren comillas simples:

```
<?php
    $codigo_fuente = "\nprint('Hola\nMundo')\n";
    $nuevo_codigo = preg_replace("/'(.*)(\\n)(.*)'/", "\\n", $codigo_fuente);
    echo $nuevo_codigo;
?>
```

Pero me da como resultado `\nprint(\n)\n`, a pesar de que busco obtener `\nprint('Hola\\nMundo')\n`

¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Podrías poner un ejemplo de texto plano con la entrada que tiene que tener, y la salida, no esta muy claro a lo que queres llegar.

Comment: O sea, en pocas palabras quiero reemplazar todas las ocurrencias de \n por \\n siempre y cuando estén contenidas en comillas dobles o simples, independiente si hay otros caracteres dentro de las comillas. Cualquier ocurrencia fuera de las comillas no debería reemplazarse. Al final el código fuente de python lo estoy considerando como un string en PHP.

Comment: Tal y como te dice [@franmost](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/41813/franmost) en su respuesta, falta conocer el origen del código fuente. Si lo estás obteniendo del contenido de un archivo, una llamada a un API, etc, entonces no necesitarías procesar ese escapado. Si lo estás "escribiendo" directamente en PHP, entonces eres tú quien debe entender que esos `\n` que usas en las comillas dobles sustituyen a escribir el código como te ha puesto de ejemplo Fran. Es decir, eres tú quien está escapando manualmente el contenido y, por lo tanto, debes escaparlo completamente y no solo esos `\n`.

Comment: Hola, el contenido del código en Python está contenido dentro de un string en PHP y conserva todos los saltos de línea, luego le paso el contenido a una API para que ejecute el código y ahí hay una confusión porque los saltos de línea los interpreta igual como si fueran parte del código, siendo que es un string y no un carácter especial. Actualicé la pregunta para que se entienda mejor. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 3):

La sustitución que has puesto es incorrecta, debería ser:

```
$nuevo = preg_replace("/'(.*)(\\n)(.*)'/", "'\1\\n\2'", $codigo_fuente);
```

Recuerda que se sustituirá la coincidencia, por lo que las comillas simples forman parte de ella, también la captura previa y posterior al retorno del carro (que se referencian como `\1` y `\2`).

Por otro lado, si nos dieras más información del API o de lo que intentas hacer te podremos ayudar a mejorar la solución porque parece que en algún punto algo estás haciendo mal (probablemente en el lado de PHP, pero no sé dónde generas o de dónde sacas el contenido de `$código_fuente` realmente).

Por ejemplo:

```
<?php
$codigo_fuente = '
print("Hola\nMundo")';
echo $codigo_fuente;
```

Donde los retornos del carro están implícitos en la cadena (al avanzar de línea sin cerrar la cadena) y las comillas simples no interpretan los `\n` como retornos del carro adicionales, si no como texto.

Si quieres que los retornos del carro normales aparezcan escapados, entonces podrías hacer uso de [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php):

```
<?php
$codigo_fuente = '
print("Hola\nMundo")';
echo json_encode($codigo_fuente);
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu comentario. Al aplicar tu expresión regular obtengo el mismo resultado. Lo ideal sería conservar el contenido que antecede las comillas. Actualicé la pregunta para que se entienda mejor. ¡Gracias nuevamente!

Comment: ¿No estarás buscando, entonces, usar `json_encode()`?

Answer (score 1):

Para cambiar **"\n"** por **"\\n"** necesitas poder operar con las contrabarras en Python (\) y para ello es necesario realizar **dos pasos**:

1. **Poner el string en texto plano** (raw) poniendo **r** delante del string
2. **Escapar la contrabarra**: realmente estás buscando una contrabarra, ya que la contrabarra Python la trata como una secuencia de escape, por lo que necesitas escapar la propia contrabarra con otra contrabarra, para poder buscar una.

Tu ejemplo quedaría así:

```
nombre = r"Bob" + r'\n'

nombre = nombre.replace('\\', '\\\\')

print(nombre)
```

Comment: Hola, sería ideal poder modificar el código de esa forma, pero resulta que se trata de código que suben estudiantes y yo por medio de PHP le paso el contenido a una API para que lo ejecute. Actualicé la pregunta para que se entienda mejor. ¡Gracias nuevamente!

Comment: @Hugo lo siento Hugo no puedo ayudarte entonces... no tengo conocimietos de PHP :(

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con lo siguiente:

```
<?php

$codigo_fuente = "\nprint('Hola\nMundo')\n";

$codigo_fuente_arreglado = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\'(?:[^\\\']+|\\.)++\'|"(?:[^\\"]+|\\.)++"/',
    function ($coincidencias) {
        return preg_replace('/\\n/', '\\\\n', $coincidencias[0]);
    },
    $codigo_fuente
);

echo "Código original: <<<$codigo_fuente>>>\n\n";
echo "Código arreglado: <<<$codigo_fuente_arreglado>>>\n\n";
```

Tienes una demo del código [aquí](https://www.ideone.com/UBtgX2).

**Cómo funciona:**

Utilizamos *[preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace-callback.php)*, que es parecido a *preg_replace*, pero admite una función como entrada. Esta función se llamará cada vez que se hagan las sustituciones.

Así pues, lo que haremos será capturar un bloque de comillas, y aplicaremos una segunda sustitución en ese bloque.

En `coinocidencias[0]` tenemos el texto encontrado. Es en ese texto donde aplicamos la segunda sustitución.

**La expresión regular explicada:**

Se compone de dos partes separados por `|`. La primera parte es el caso para capturar con comillas simples, y el segundo caso captura las comillas dobles.

Para facilitar la visualización y comprensión, únicamente explicaré aquí el primer caso, ya que el segundo es análogo cambiando el tipo de comilla.

También, ten en cuenta que como para definir la expresión regular he utilizado comillas simples (por ejemplo `'/blabla/'`), si la expresión regular tiene comillas dentro, hay que escaparlas. Por eso en el código php, la expresión de las comillas simples es algo más larga que la de comillas dobles.

```
'        # Comilla simple
(?:      # Una de estas opciones:
      [^\\']++  # Un caracter que no puede ser contrabarra o comilla simple, una o más veces
    | \\.       # Una contrabarra y cualquier caracter a continuación
)++      # Todo el grupo repetido una o más veces
'        # Comilla simple (cierra)
```

Tienes una demo de la expresión regular [aquí](https://regex101.com/r/M8mCdt/2/).